# Create view for multi relational tables sql-server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to create a view to display Department Name, Count of Employees, Total Salary and Count of Projects for this department

[image: database digram]

and here is my query but no data is returned:

```
SELECT  d.[DeprtmentName] ,
    count(e.[Id]) AS Employees,
    sum(e.[Salary]) AS [Total Salary],
    count(p.[Id]) AS Pojects
FROM [dbo].[Department] as d
join [dbo].[Employee] as e on d.id = e.[DeptId]
join [dbo].[ProjectEmployee] as p on e.id = p.[EmployeeId]
join [dbo].[Project] on p.[ProjectId] = [dbo].[Project].[Id] 
group by (d.[DeprtmentName])
```

Comment: You may want to use left join in case any of the tables don't have a match (which might be the issue here). Also if you could provide a couple of rows of sample data  it will enable assistance.

Comment: Projects can have employees from any department, so a single project may be counted many times... i.e. the result may not be what you expect/want. If you don't specify your requirement you could be disappointed . What happens if an employee changes department? by the way: left join the 2 project related tables

Comment: Additionally to the left joins @DaleBurrell already suggested, you probably want `count(DISTINCT p.[Id])` instead of `count(p.[Id])`. More than one employee of a department can be assigned to a project. That means that project gets joined and therefore more than once.

Comment: Yes, thank you it's all about data, when i provide dozen of rows it's executed as  i want thanks